# How can I compare two lists and output "hits" into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, igraph

I've tried to find answers here and on google but no luck, been struggling with this issue for some days so would really appreciate help. I'm analyzing a network to see if cycles tend to be within discreet communities or between them, or no pattern. My data are a list of cycles (three nodes forming a loop) and a list of communities (variable amount of nodes). I have two questions, 1) how to compare two lists, and 2) how to output the comparison results in a way which is readable:

- Question 1

I have two lists (both igraph objects), one containing 678 items (each of 3 elements, all characters) and another containing 11 items each with a differing number of elements. Example:

```
x1 <- as.character(c(1,3,5))
x2 <- as.character(c(2,4,6))
x3 <- as.character(c(7,8,9))
x4 <- as.character(c(10,11,12))
x <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4)

y1 <- as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5))
y2 <- as.character(c(2,3,4,5))
y3 <- as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9))
y <- list(y1, y2, y3)
```

Giving:

```
> x
[[1]]
[1] "1" "3" "5"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "4" "6"

[[3]]
[1] "7" "8" "9"

[[4]]
[1] "10" "11" "12"

> y
[[1]]
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"

[[2]]
[1] "2" "3" "4" "5"

[[3]]
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "7" "8" "9"
```

I want to compare every component in `x` against every component in `y` and add every hit (i.e. when all the elements from `x[[i]]` are also found in `y[[i]]`) to a new dataframe. I tried a loop using `all()` and `%in%` but this didn't work:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  for (j in 1:length(y)) {
    hits <- all(y[[j]] %in% x[[i]]) == TRUE
    print(hits)
      }
    }
```

This returns 12 `FALSE` hits. Checking individual components, it should have worked, because:

```
all(x[[1]] %in% y[[1]])
```

Returns `TRUE` as it should, and:

```
all(x[[1]] %in% y[[2]])
```

Returns `FALSE` as it should. Where am I going wrong here?

- Question 2

I have seen some solutions for outputting loop results into a df, but that's not exactly what I need. What I want as an output is a dataframe telling me which community every cycle is in. Since there's only 11 communities, it could just refer me to the list component's index, but I haven't found a way to do this. I could also just use `paste()` to concatenate the node names of a community into a title. Either way, here is the output I need:

```
  cycle       community
1 1_3_5       1_2_3_4_5
2 1_3_5 1_2_3_4_5_7_8_9
3 7_8_9 1_2_3_4_5_7_8_9
```

I'm guessing some kind of an if statement. I feel this should be fairly simple to execute and that I should have been able to work it out myself. Nevertheless, thank you for your time and sorry about the essay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    for (j in 1:length(y)) {
    # hits <- all(y[[j]] %in% x[[i]]) == TRUE
    hits <- all(x[[i]] %in% y[[j]]) == TRUE
    print(hits)
    }
}
```

For the second part you can store the indexes that have a hit and use them for later.

```
a <- list()
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    for (j in 1:length(y)) {
    # hits <- all(y[[j]] %in% x[[i]]) == TRUE
    hits <- all(x[[i]] %in% y[[j]]) == TRUE
    if(hits == TRUE){
        a[[length(a)+1]] <- c(i,j)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YES. thank you =D. this gives me a list with ~400 index pairs, the cycle and community, so it's just a matter of wrangling this list.

Answer (score 1):

The final part of the question, creation of cycle and community tags, can be accomplished with `stringi::stri_join()` (or `paste()` as pointed out in the comments).  The final step to wrangle the list created in Jt Miclat's answer is as follows, using the indexes in the list `a` to extract the appropriate strings for `cycle` and `community`, generate data frames, and `rbind()` the result to a single data frame.

```
# combine with cycle & community tags 
cycles <- sapply(x,paste,collapse="_")
communities <- sapply(y,paste,collapse="_")
b <- lapply(a,function(x){
     cycle <- cycles[x[1]]
     community <- communities[x[2]]
     data.frame(x=x[1],y=x[2],cycle=cycle,community=community,
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
df <- do.call(rbind,b)
df
```

...and the output:

```
> df <- do.call(rbind,b)
> df
  x y cycle       community
1 1 1 1_3_5       1_2_3_4_5
2 1 3 1_3_5 1_2_3_4_5_7_8_9
3 3 3 7_8_9 1_2_3_4_5_7_8_9
>
```

Comment: If at all this was the objective, then there would be no need of all that you are doing, you could as well do `sapply(x,paste,collapse="_")` for cycle and `sapply(y,paste,collapse="_")` for community. But read the question again. This answer is completely unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make use of `outer`:

```
  outer(x,y,function(w,z)Map(function(i,j)all(i%in%j),w,z))->results
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`x` is the rows while `y` is the columns, so to check `all(x[[1]]%in%y[[2]])`,just check row 1 column 2 ie element [1,2] etc..

Then you can use `apply` with a own created function:

```
 fun<-function(i)c(paste(x[[i[1]]],collapse ="_"), paste(y[[i[2]]],collapse ="_"))
 t(apply(which(result==T,T),1,fun))
     [,1]    [,2]             
[1,] "1_3_5" "1_2_3_4_5"      
[2,] "1_3_5" "1_2_3_4_5_7_8_9"
[3,] "7_8_9" "1_2_3_4_5_7_8_9"
```

Comment: thanks for this, i like the idea and the results matrix! i didn't end up using it though because i feel it's unwieldy for the number of results in my actual data

Comment: Well though you can still upvote it as it solves the problem

Comment: i did ;) but my reputation is too low for it to count